# How to make the border stretch to its parents full height in CSS?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to learn css and right now i'm trying to recreate this [template](https://cheerup.theme-sphere.com/miranda/blog/2016/05/14/my-loving-partner/). The header was pretty simple however I couldn't create the vertical line between the search icon and the shopping bag icon [see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0y0Bb.png) (cart), my idea was to use a border-right on the search icon and but the border's height won't reach the height that I want.

Here is my code [`JSFiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/z7cstmj0/)

Comment: If you use your browser devtools inspect facility you will see that that whole line is a list of nav items and the two icons at the end are within an element which has the right height for the border you want.

Comment: I did but I couldn't find it

Comment: Right click on an item in the naavbar and step back to find the parent structure.

Comment: Please do not circumvent the quality filter. Paste your code in the question. For help, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do

Answer (score 0):

Please see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kameronmayers/uknvrygq/27/) for the code you're looking for. It appears that you didn't have your child classes `search-icon` and `cart-icon` in your parent. This is why using a height selector wouldn't work. Also, you were trying to make the line part of one of the existing bootstrap logo divs which is not ideal for trying to optimize that line. I created a new div called `harambe-div` - Everything should be noted where changes were made.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I did have my child classes in the nav-cart parent, please check again, however is this the only way to do it? is there other ways to do that? @Kameron

Comment: @RashidDev yea I noticed that now. This is not the only way to do it but it is the easiest way to do it with your given HTML format.

Answer (score 0):

It happen because the unordered list(ul) is having a margin of it's own by default. You can see it in chrome devtool. Set the margin to 0 in "nav ul", give a height to the class ".search-icon" ,align things a little and you are ready to go :)

```
nav ul {
  margin: 0;
}
.search-icon {
  height: 40px;
}
```